# Vue.js: Don't render attributes if value is empty (e.g.: to="" or type="")

Tags: javascript, vue.js, properties, vue-component

I have Button component which renders a nuxt-link or a button depending if you provide some attribute like `to` or `type`.

```
<div class="Btn">
  <component
    :class="['Btn__button', createAppearanceClasses]"
    v-on:click="click"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :is="type"
    :to="to"
    :href="external ? to : false"
    :target="target"
    :type="buttonType"
    >
    <slot />
  </component>
</div>
```

(Whereas the `type` is a computed property to return a `nuxt-link` for internal links, a `a` tag if it is an external link or a `button` if these properties are not defined)

Now we sometimes render some Buttons which open a Modal or submit. There we don't pass any type or to attribute:

```
<Btn :class="'FlexContent__button'" 
  :appearance="['rounded-corners']"
  v-on:click.native="openOverlay" 
>    
 {{ component.text }}
</Btn>
```

In the rendered HTML I get:

`<button disabled to="" target="" type="" class="Btn__button Btn__button--rounded-corners">`

If I validate this I get errors concerning these empty attributes:
`Attribute to not allowed on element button at this point.`

How can I render the attribute `to=""` only if I have an actual value passed to the Btn component?

I was thinking about something like this, but this does not work:
    `(to ? ':to="to"' : '')`
So I need some other solution for this.

Thanks in advance for hints.

cheers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Any attribute that is bound using `v-bind` to a value that is `null`, `undefined`, or `false` will not be rendered in the element.

[Attributes and v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Comment: That's what I thought too. Thanks to your answer, I realized that the prop had an empty default value: `props: {
    to: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      required: false
    },` I set the default to `false` and now everything is ok.
thx

Comment: It appears in Vue3 that a false value is actually rendered as `attribute="false"`, null and undefined are not rendered.

Comment: Vue 3 documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings